# Building a docker image (.NET Core) and uploading it to Google Container Engine?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, google-kubernetes-engine

I have an ASP.NET Core app in Visual Studio 2017 with added Docker support and I have created a free trial on Google Container Engine to see if I can host this app as a container. But I'm really totally confused by just about everything...

First of all, I just need to understand how to build the image on my Windows machine (if that is even how it should be done? or should it always be built on the server side?), and then how to deploy it? I also have Docker for Windows installed, if that is needed.

I did run this command (in the folder with my dockerfile) because I figured it was perhaps what I should do:

```
docker build -t myapp:v1 .
```

It was successful but I have no idea where the resulting image went? I can't find any new files created that looks to be the image.

And then how do I deploy this to Google?

In the docs, I read this:

```
gcloud docker -- push gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/hello-node:v1
```

What does that translate to for me? I'm running a Cloud Shell in Chrome. Can I use that to push the image from my local drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you build your image locally, you should check all images on your machine:

```
docker images
```

See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/ for details

THen you have to tag your image properly

```
docker tag 0e5574283393 gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/hello-node:v1
```

See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/#extended-description for more detals.
If you list now your images, you'll have two with different tags but the same UUID. NOw you should be able to push it to GKE.